# How can I change the collapsable 'more' into 'less' once expanded?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p class="collapse" id="collapseSpeed">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSpeed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSpeed">more...</a>
```

This works nicely. I can click on `more` to expand and show the second paragraph. But it's odd that it still says `more`. Is there any way to change it to `less` once it has been expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you conditions to change the innerHTML to toggle the text:

```js
$( "a" ).click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass("open");
    
        if ($this.hasClass("open")) {
            $this.html("less...");
        } else {
            $this.html("more...");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">more...</a>
```

This code will (once clicked) toggle a class to the `A` tag of 'open' (and if clicked again, be taken off) and then run the condition of if there is a class of open attached to the `A` tag, then the `html` of the `A` tag (`$this`) will be changed. Otherwise, if there is no class, the `html` will be changed back.

Comment: Thanks. but your `a` has no `open` specified, where does it come from? Update: I think you are injecting it in via `$this.toggleClass("open");`  If you could explain that a bit more, could be great.

Comment: At the top of the function, once the button has been clicked, the class of open is then added to the a tag by "$this.toggleClass("open");". This means that each time the a tag is clicked, the code will alternately add a class of open to the a tag or take it off. Once this part has been done, the condition work happens where if the class is present or not, the html text is changed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that today.  A shame that this can't be done with CSS directly, without any js.

Comment: No problem, off the top of my head I wouldn't think this could be done with CSS just because you will need conditional work to work out if the button has been clicked and then clicked again to change the text. I do think using JavaScript is the wisest option. This option will work for what you are trying so should hopefully not have any issues.

Comment: Thank you. I will try today, once I have access to my laptop again. And let you know. cheers